# the_post_thumbnail doesn't resize properly

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am using the_post_thumbnail and when I do the image will not resize properly.  It retains the height so it just squeezes down until the media query kicks in.  When I just load the image via my cdn it works perfect.  This is only with the post thumbnail.   I have tried setting the image size via functions.php file and then loading in the name.....but still the same.

Any suggestions?  Thank you

Comment: That function accepts a parameter for the size. Can you share the code, and what file it's in?

Comment: <?php the_post_thumbnail('service-feature'); ?> (in template file).....add_image_size('service-feature', '600', '400', 'true'); (in functions.php)  I get the image but it won't resize as expected.

Comment: Ok, so it's pulling the right image? That sounds like a CSS issue then rather than a WP issue.

Comment: I don't think it is CSS...if i go back to loading the image from my cdn into the same element it works perfectly...it's definitely weird